# Extract URL from incoming Mail and open in background

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I'm regularly receiving the following message:

```
Dear User,

SSH access to the cluster has been requested from 111111.public.t-mobile.de (IP 000.000.00.000).
If this was you, please activate the SSH access within the next 10 minutes using this activation link: https://fileshare.bla.domain.ac.com/ssh2fa/index.php?action=enable&sshcli=000.000.00.000&sshusr=user&key2fa=ee03a88e62574e3449e610f323e611e9947fb2d3

Otherwise, just ignore this message. If you should receive such mails frequently, please let us know: contact@domain.com

best regards and happy computing
your team
```

With this email I'm receiving a link to activate an ssh login. Simply clicking on the link is enough (the webpage that opens is not important or informative). I would like to extract the URL starting with `https://`, and open it. It does not actually have to open (ie. it can also be in background).
I found some solutions using applescript, but those usually fail because the URL is quite complex, and I would appreciate some help!

This is what I came up with so far:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
            tell application "Mail" to set t to (content of eachMessage) as string -- EDITED
            set t to paragraphs of t -- ADDED
            repeat with i in t
                if i starts with "https://fileshare.bla.domain.ac.com/ssh2fa/index.php?action=enable&sshcli=" then openLocation(i)
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from

on openLocation(theURL)
    tell application "Safari" to open location theURL
end openLocation
```